# Will visual studio 2010 express support addins?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, add-in, visual-studio-express

I know vs2008 express didn't. I'm hoping this will change with vs2010. Anyone know? Link me?

**Edit:**

Anyone have a primary source? While "As far as I know" answers can be helpful, in this case it still leaves a possibility - which is exactly where I started.

Comment: Have a look at question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7940249/723845

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know, but I would guess that it would not.  Microsoft wants to make money, and supporting ad-ins is one of the biggest reasons to pony up the dough for the standard edition.  Ad-in support alone can replace a lot of the stuff that you pay for, like SVN and other source control integration, test framework integration, resharper, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but it came up on a search for "Visual Studio 2012 Express Add-ins".

Here is a quote from [a post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/7ef7fce3-76f4-41ad-b306-83b9dad5379e) by Ryan Molden (MSFT) on the Visual Studio forums:

> "Express does not support AddIns. The reason it has the extension manager is that it supports project/item templates."

My experience is that the same applies to Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the policy regarding Add-In's and Express editions has not changed.