# Restrictions on installing extensions or add-ins in Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I installed MSVC++ 2010 Express and trying to figure which extensions (vsix) are available to install. There are some extensions in the *Extension Manager* (section *Online Gallery*). All of them from [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/). To be sure I installed some [extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9df9c61c-4d90-43e5-9aa1-a58786b7a1e4). It, therefore, cannot be said that the express editions of Visual Studio do not support installing Extensions or Add-Ins. At first I decided that *Visual Studio Gallery* is the place for allowed extensions. I downloaded from there [PowerConsole](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3/) extension and tried to install it. However, I got message box with following text:

> Visual Studio Extension Installer
>   This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

The question is, What are *exact* limitations for installing extensions in Visual Studio 2010 Express?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at this [article](http://www.go4answers.com/Example/installing-vsix-file-vb2010-express-5068.aspx).

In summary from above article:

- The Express SKUs only support installation of extensions  that are classified as Templates (or Template Wizards) and Controls.
- The Express SKUs do not support tool extensions. Which is anything that doesn't fall into one of the other
  categories (Template or Control).
- VSIX files  are marked, via the manifest, as to which applications they are compatible and can be installed.

Comment: Does this mean that careful editing of the manifest can change where they can be installed?

Comment: According to the quoted article, it seems like it is a limitation of the express editions not being able to load tool extensions. The manifest would be for a template or controls that the author was restricting.