# Visual Studio extension installing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, add-on

I have downloaded a Visual Studio extension. How can I install it to Visual Studio? (Note I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very simple. You run the extension (*.vsix) like you would run an application and it will automatically install itself to your `Visual Studio` installation.

You can then start `Visual Studio` and go to `Tools => Extension Manager` to confirm that the `Extension` was installed successfully.

Keep in mind that `Extensions` are only supported on the `Premium` versions of `Visual Studio` and it's not possible to use them on the `Visual Studio Express` editions.

Comment: Ah Im using an express edition, double clicking it was the first thing i tried. Oh well..

Comment: Yes. I figured as much but I thought I would cover the basics just in case, but yea not possible unless you upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Not all extensions can be installed on an Express Edition. See this stackoverflow [question\answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940249/restrictions-on-installing-extensions-or-add-ins-in-visual-studio-2010-express) for more details of which types are compatible.