# Adding extensions in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Window8 Desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, vsix, .net-reflector

I realise that VS2012 Express Edition now supports NuGet packages. Any idea if the limitations on adding productivity tools like Resharper or Reflector in VS Express Editions 2012 has now been changed? I've drawn some reference from [Restrictions on installing extensions or add-ins in Visual Studio 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940249/restrictions-on-installing-extensions-or-add-ins-in-visual-studio-2010-express). However, I'm looking for whether the behavior has changed with VS 2012.

Comment: Nope still the same. Also, I went looking last night, and even installed as an extension, I could not see how to actually use Nuget from Express.

Comment: I suspect NuGet is pre-bundled in VS2012. Is there nothing on the Tools menu?

Answer (score 13):

This limitation is likely to be virtually forever. The rationale for this is that an Express addition plus plugins could very well be everything people need, removing the incentive to buy the 'paid' versions of VS. IIRC, the author of TestDriven.NET has had his MVP status revoked after making his plug-in compatible with VS Express.