# Any other extensions for Visual Studio C++ 2010 express like Visual Assist X?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Any Alternative extensions for Visual Studio C++ 2010 express like Visual Assist X ?

Comment: I don't think you can install extensions in the express edition, can you?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940249/restrictions-on-installing-extensions-or-add-ins-in-visual-studio-2010-express - you can't install tool extensions into VS2010 Express.

Answer (score 1):

I am personally not aware of any. I don't think VS2010 Express supports VAX to begin with.

Since you only mention C++ - if you want a decent **FREE** IDE with good "intellisense", auto-complete, refactoring, snippets and code generation (the hallmarks of VAX) - I recommend [Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator). It is originally intended for using with the Qt framework, but can be used standalone with any compiler you want. It is smaller and faster than VS, plus it is portable and has the advantage of being a fully fledged product, where VS Express is a cut down version.

Last time I checked, Eclipse was also doing well in this regard, but it is a little clumsy and heavy, probably because it is written in Java.