# Visual Studio 2013 Extensions Not Installing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I have Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop installed on my Windows 8.1 PC, for which I would like to install an extension to create a vertical line limiter so that my code lines won't exceed a certain length. However, when I downloaded the extension I wanted (called Editor Guidelines -- the version for VS2012 and VS2013, that is) and tried to install it, I got an error message:

> **Installation Failed**
>
> The installation was unable to install the extension to all the selected products. For more information, click on the install log link at the bottom of the dialog.
>
> This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

This appears to be an issue with all extensions that I try to install onto VS through its inbuilt VSIX Installer. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can work around this, if there is a setting within Visual Studio 12.0 that deals with a vertical line limiter, or if there is a way to do so from the Windows Registry?

(On a sidenote, I've tried adding a key to the Windows Registry under "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\" called "Text Editor", which didn't exist before, and adding a String key under that called "Guides" and associating the string value "RGB(192,192,192) 110", but to no avail.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrictions on installing extensions or add-ins in Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940249/restrictions-on-installing-extensions-or-add-ins-in-visual-studio-2010-express) even though this is for vs2010 it still holds true

Answer (score 4):

Extension cannot be installed into Express versions of Visual Studio. You get that error message since the VSIX installer is skipping past the Express versions of VS when it's looking for places to install it, and thus it finds nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can install Visual Studio 2013 Community that is free and fully extensible: http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs