# Can I install extensions in Visual Basic Express 2010? Trying to add an indent guides extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, indentation, visual-studio-extensions

I downloaded an extension that adds indent guides, but when I try to install it, I get an error saying "this extension cant be installed on any currently installed programs"

[The extension](http://indentguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/110312) is supposed to work on Visual Studio 2010.

Is it because I have VB 2010 Express and not VB 2010 Professional? I would really appreciate it if someone could help me fix this so I can get these very helpful indent guides in VB.

Answer (score 0):

Proper support for extensions require a Community version of Visual Studio which is free like Express. Express supports some types of extensions, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940249/restrictions-on-installing-extensions-or-add-ins-in-visual-studio-2010-express) by Mark Hall:

> The Express SKUs only support installation of extensions that are
> classified as Templates (or Template Wizards) and Controls.
>
> The Express SKUs do not support tool extensions. Which is anything that
> doesn't fall into one of the other categories (Template or Control).
>
> VSIX files are marked, via the manifest, as to which applications they
> are compatible and can be installed.

Comment: In my Visual Studio 2010 Express I can open the Extension Manager.

Comment: @Alex_dlc, I added some information regarding extension support in Express edition.